# How to access the private data studio report?

Tags: report, looker-studio

We are creating private report for clients from our google account. We want our clients to access these reports from our web application (using iframe embed option). As reports are private it is not accessible from our web application.

Could you please provide suggestions on how we can achieve such functionality?

Comment: Please tell us what you have done already. Share your code, otherwise no one can help you.

Comment: How do you create that private reports which are non accessible from your web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the report editor:

1. Click **File** | **Share...** to open the sharing dialog.
2. Click the **Advanced** link in the lower right to see a (somewhat) easier to understand list of visibility options.

These are the only options available for sharing the report.

The easiest one is probably the second, "only those who have the link can see the report." The general public won't be able to find your report, but the general public could see it if a user of your web application inspected the `src` of the iframe and shared the URL with others.